# How to checked the checkbox if my checkbox is using html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i checked the checkbox if the data is already in the database as selected by user ? For normal html, i can use checked , however, im using javascript for this one. is there any way to edit the html instead of the javascript ?

```
 <td><div align="center"><span class="formlist">
      <select id="plant" name="plant[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
        <?php 
                    $query_plant = "SELECT * FROM plant WHERE plant_enable=1 ORDER BY plant_name";
                    $rs_plant = DB_Query($query_plant);

                    while ($row_plant = DB_FetchRow($rs_plant)) {

                        $plant.='<option value='.$row_plant["plant_id"].'>' .$row_plant["plant_name"].' ['.$row_plant["plant_id"].']</option>';

                        }   

                    mysql_free_result($rs_plant);
                    echo $plant;
                ?>
      </select>
    </span></div></td>
```

[image]

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#plant').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
    $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
                var selected = $("#plant option:selected");
                var message = "";
                selected.each(function () {
                    message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
                });
                alert(message);
            });
            
               });
    </script>
```

Comment: Checkbox or dropdown?

Comment: if($option==$db_stored_option) { echo "checked" }

Comment: @ArunKumaresh dropdown with checkbox.

Comment: You are not cleared with the problem because you said you want to check the checkbox but the code shows the dropdown. First describe the problem correctly so that the readers can contribute to your question.

Comment: @YashParekh I have updated the question with pictures

Comment: @ArunKumaresh I have updated the question with pictures

Comment: @JYoThI but im using javascript

Comment: is it okay to select using javascript ? @NFSJ

Comment: @JYoThI yes i think it is okay since ive already done it and successfully inserted the data in database. however, the issue that im facing now is that i want to automatically checked the box if the element has already been recorded in the database for the specific user.

Comment: try my updated answer @NFSJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First you can add  **selected** attribute to options which is user already selected and stored in database . like this

```
 $userPlants = [1,2,3,4];  //fetched value from database . previously user selected .

<option value="<?php echo $row_plant["plant_id"] ?>"

          <?php 

          if(in_array($row_plant["plant_id"], $userPlants)) 
           {
               echo " selected";
           } 

           ?>
><?php echo $row_plant["plant_name"] ?></option>
```

```js
$(function () {
            $('#plant').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
            
   // $("#plant").multiselect("refresh");  //if you need to refresh the multiselect use like this .

              });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    

<td><div align="center"><span class="formlist">
      <select id="plant" name="plant[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
<option value='option1'>option1</option>
<option value='option2' selected >option2</option>
<option value='option3' selected >option3</option>
<option value='option4'>option4</option>
<option value='option5'>option5</option>

                ?>
      </select>
    </span></div></td>
```

Comment: Im sorry for taking quite a time to try this code as i was kinda busy with other codes. but i will try this code and get back to you soon. thank you very much! :D

Comment: i read documentation and prepared this answer hopefully it will help you @NFSJ

Comment: you need to place the selected property based on that if condition @NFSJ

Comment: glad to help you @NFSJ

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of all plants that user has already selected. And then do it like this

```
  <td><div align="center"><span class="formlist">
  <select id="plant" name="plant[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <?php        
            // query to fetch user palnts and crate an array
            $userPlants = [1231,1281,1241,1271];                       


                $query_plant = "SELECT * FROM plant WHERE plant_enable=1 ORDER BY plant_name";
                $rs_plant = DB_Query($query_plant);

                while ($row_plant = DB_FetchRow($rs_plant)) {

                    $plant.='<option value='.$row_plant["plant_id"];

                    if (in_array($row_plant["plant_id"], $userPlants)) {
                        echo " checked ";
                    }

                    $plant.= '>' .$row_plant["plant_name"].' ['.$row_plant["plant_id"].']</option>';

                    }   

                mysql_free_result($rs_plant);
                echo $plant;
            ?>
  </select>
</span></div></td>
```

Comment: the main point is the checked keyword right ? it is not working. ive tried before using the checked keyword but it didnt work..

Comment: Thank you for this as i finally able to understand more and modified this code and finally getting the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <select id="plant" name="plant[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" >
        <?php 
                    $query_po = "SELECT * FROM plant WHERE plant_enable=1 ORDER BY plant_name";
                    $rs_po = DB_Query($query_po);

                    while ($row_po = DB_FetchRow($rs_po)) { ?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $row_po["plant_id"] ?>"
                        <?php 
                                $user_sql = "SELECT * FROM plant_access WHERE staff_id = '".$STAFF_ID."'";
                                $user_res = DB_Query($user_sql);

                                while($user_row = DB_FetchRow($user_res)) { 
                                    if($row_po["plant_id"] == $user_row["temp_plant_code"]){
                                        {
                                               echo " selected";
                                           } 


                                    } ?>


                                <?php
                                }   

                                     ?>
                                <?php echo $row_po["plant_name"] ?></option>

                    <?php
                    echo $row_po["plant_name"] ;
            } ?>
      </select>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
```

Credit to :  @jYoThl

Comment: This is my modified code that answers what i want :)